# Compare views.total_rows in twig file

Tags: views, theming, search

Original Code:

```
<div class="our-story search-query">
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Search Results</h1>
  {% if keysearch %} 
  <p>{{ view.total_rows }} results found for '<span class="font-500">{{ keysearch }}</span>'</p>  
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  </div>
```

I have this code in a twig file. I need to put in a condition:
 1. If search results are ZERO, then it should say "No results found for 'YYY' "
 2. If results are found i.e above Zero, then it should say " XX results found for 'YYY' "

Code with If condition:

```
{% if keysearch %} 
  {% set variable = {{ view.total_rows }} %}
  {% if variable > 0 %}  
  <p>{{ view.total_rows }} results found for '<span class="font-500">{{ keysearch }}</span>'</p>
else {
 <p>No results found for '<span class="font-500">{{ keysearch }}</span>'</p>
}  
  {% endif %}
```

When I put in a condition under `{% if keysearch %} it throws an error:

Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in "themes/custom/iifl/templates/views/views-view--search-page.html.twig" at line 59. in Twig_ExpressionParser->parseHashExpression() (line 281 of vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php).

Can someone help me out.

Comment: This is a Twig syntax issue rather than anything to do with Drupal; `{% set variable = {{ view.total_rows }} %}` needs to be `{% set variable =  view.total_rows %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    {% if keysearch %} 
  {% set variable = {{ view.total_rows }} %}
  {% if variable > 0 %}  
  <p>{{ view.total_rows }} results found for '<span class="font-500">{{ keysearch }}</span>'</p>
{% else %}
 <p>No results found for '<span class="font-500">{{ keysearch }}</span>'</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Do not know if this is the case , but your else condition is not twig like.